# Why does the Jackson still serialize the long[] as number array?

Tags: java, arrays, jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

        module.addSerializer(Long.class, ToStringSerializer.instance);
        module.addSerializer(Long.TYPE, ToStringSerializer.instance);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        Long l1 = 1L;
        long l2 = 1L;
        Long[] ls1 = new Long[]{1L, 2L};
        long[] ls2 = new long[]{1L, 2L};

        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(l1));
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(l2));
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ls1));
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ls2));
    }
}
```

for this code snippet, the output is:

```
"1"
"1"
["1","2"]
[1,2]
```

would you explain the reason why ls2 is serialized as [1, 2]? i thought it should be ["1", 2].

Comment: Because Jackson relies on a set of internal serializer implementations for `long[]` and the other primitive typed arrays. For `long[]`, it's `StdArraySerializers.LongArraySerializer`.

Comment: Actually, the thing that surprises me is that either of `writeValueAsString(ls1)` and `writeValueAsString(ls2)` produces a JSON array.  I'd have expected it to always produce a JSON string.  (Based on the method name ...)

Comment: @StephenC It _does_ write it as a string, containing JSON, the value of which is an array.